# What's the reason of int* conversion not permitted to int error?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int minimu ( int a, int b, int c );

int main (void)
{
    int t,i,j;
    cin>>t;
    while ( t != 0 )
    {
        string a;
        string b;
        cin>>a>>b;
        int k;
        int len1 = a.length();
        int len2 = b.length();
        int dp[len1][len2];
        dp[0][0] = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < len1; i++ )
        {
            dp[i][0] = i;
        }
        for ( j = 0; j < len2; j++ )
        {
            dp[0][j] = j;
        }
        for ( i = 1; i < len1; i++ )
            for ( j = 1; j < len2; j++ )
            {
                if ( a[i] == b[j] )
                    k = 2;
                else
                    k = 0;  
                dp[i][j] = minimu(dp[i-1,j]+1,dp[i,j-1]+1,dp[i-1][j-1]+k);
            }
         cout<<dp[len1-1][len2-1]<<"\n";
         t--;
     }
     return 0;
}

int minimu ( int a, int b, int c )
{
    int foo = min(a,min(b,c));
    return foo;
}
```

This is the program for calculating the minimum number of operations while converting one string to another string. The only allowed operations for converting are:

```
1. Deleting a character
2. Inserting a character
3. Substituting a character
```

Now, when I compile this program, it shows the error that:

> invalid conversion from int* to int[-fpermissive]

in the line where I update the 2-D array `dp[i,j]`. Why is that happening?

Comment: `int dp[len1][len2];` where `len1` and `len2` are not constants, is **not valid** standard C++. g++ supports this as a language extension (borrowed from C99). In C++ use e.g. `std::vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the declaration:

> int dp[len1][len2];

`dp[i-1,j]` is an *array*, not an *element of the matrix*. (Here `comma operator` can be confusing, as **@BartoszKP** has explained.)

Perhaps

```
minimu(dp[i-1,j]+1,dp[i,j-1]+1,dp[i-1][j-1]+k);
```

should be

```
minimu(dp[i-1][j]+1,dp[i][j-1]+1,dp[i-1][j-1]+k);
//           ^          ^
```

**P.S.** Please note that `int dp[len1][len2];` with non-const sizes is not valid according to C++ standard, as **@Cheers and hth** said.

Answer (score 2):

```
dp[i-1,j]
```

This does not access the element in the `i-1`th row and the `j`th column.

The expression inside the brackets is using the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) which ignores `i-1` and evaluates to `j`.
So the expression is equivalent to `dp[j]`, which is certainly wrong; the array to which `dp[j]` refers cannot be converted to an `int`, and the above error message comes up because the compiler tried to decay the array to a pointer and convert that pointer to `int` (which of course doesn't work either).

You meant to write `dp[i-1][j]`.

Answer (score 2):

The expression of form `[i,j]`, even though it looks similar to two-dimensional indexing (like in C# or Python), is unfortunately against intuition here: it uses the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). This operator will evaluate all expressions and return the result of the *last expression* as an ultimate result. So, effectively you are indexing your 2D array only once (`dp[i-1,j]` ~ `dp[j]`) which yields `int*` instead of `int`.

Use `dp[i-1][j]` instead.